# Neovim - `gf` unable to find file in path

Tags: lua, neovim

**Problem**

From my init.lua, I'd like to use `gf` to jump to a config file that I have required. E.g.

```
require("keymaps")
require("plugins")
...
```

Pressing `gf` returns the following error:
`E447: Can't find file "keymaps" in path`.

**My attemps at solving this**

This is what my config directory looks like

```
.
├── ftplugin
│   └── python.lua
├── init.lua
└── lua
    ├── keymaps.lua
    └── plugins.lua
```

I have tried to append the above directory to my vim path variable but my issue persists.
In my init.vim:

```
o.path = o.path .. ".config/nvim/lua/**,"
```

---

Following advice from user @Amadan below, here are more diagnostics. Problem still persists.

```
-- Changes made
o.path = o.path .. "~/.config/nvim/lua/**,"
```

:set path?

```
path=.,/usr/include,,~/.config/nvim/lua/**,
```

:set suffixesadd?

```
suffixesadd=.lua
```

:find plugins

```
E345: Can't find file "plugins" in path
```

:find lua.plugins

```
E345: Can't find file "plugins" in path
```

:find lua/plugins

```
No idea why but this works. But using `require("lua/plugins")` does not.
```

Comment: `.config/nvim/lua/**` is a relative path, and should work as long as your Vim is in your home directory. To make it universally usable, use `~/.config/nvim/lua/**` instead. If that still doesn't work, please report `:set path?` and `set suffixesadd?`, as some defaults might be disturbed.

Comment: @Amadan : Thanks for advice. Problem persists even after using `o.path = o.path .. ".config/nvim/lua/**,"`.


:set path? output
`path=.,/usr/include,,~/.config/nvim/lua/**,`


:set suffixesadd? output
`suffixesadd=.lua`

Comment: Check your `stdpath` for nvim with `:echo stdpath("config")` => must be `$HOME/.config/nvim/`

Comment: Yeap, I just ran `:echo stdpath("config")` and indeed it is pointing to `$HOME/.config/nvim`

Comment: You can also check your `runtime_paths` with command `:lua print(vim.inspect(vim.api.nvim_list_runtime_paths()))`

Comment: Perplexingly, I do see `$HOME/.config/nvim` as one of the runtime paths after running `:lua print(vim.inspect(vim.api.nvim_list_runtime_paths()))`

Comment: I have even tried reinstalling neovim to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

that method works well for me:

```
-- Options to add `gf` functionality inside `.lua` files.
_G.vim.opt_local.include = [[\v<((do|load)file|require)[^''"]*[''"]\zs[^''"]+]]
_G.vim.opt_local.includeexpr = "substitute(v:fname,'\\.','/','g')"
for _, path in pairs(_G.vim.api.nvim_list_runtime_paths()) do
    _G.vim.opt_local.path:append(path .. '/lua')
end
_G.vim.opt_local.suffixesadd:prepend('.lua')
```

borrowed from [this plugin](https://github.com/sam4llis/nvim-lua-gf/blob/main/after/ftplugin/lua.lua) in github